# Executing SQL queries from Terraform on RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I am trying to use something like this to execute a sql script to create the table and users:

```
data "local_file" "sql_script" {
  filename = "${path.module}../infra-main/db.sql"
}


resource "null_resource" "setup_db" {
  depends_on = [aws_db_instance.grafana-db]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "mysql -u ${var.username} -p${var.password} -h ${aws_db_instance.grafana-db.address} < ${data.local_file.sql_script.content}"
  }
}
```

But I don't understand what to put for the file path. Everything I try, it says "no such file or directory". The path I'm using is from my IDE.

[image]

Comment: Could we see the actual error message? Based on the question information, this could just as easily imply that `mysql` is not installed on your local device.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I also installed SQL as well and it still errored. `Error: open .../infra-main/db.sql: no such file or directory
with data.local_file.sql_script
on main.tf line 345, in data "local_file" "sql_script":
data "local_file" "sql_script" {`

Comment: Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/OBExX8q1Nui7.png

Comment: From the error it can not find that file ... can you share the structure of your code?  Have you successfully  used `data "local_file"` before ?

Comment: I was looking at my use of path.module and I always have a slash after it something like `"${path.module}/../infra-main/db.sql"`  try that see if it works for you

Comment: Thank you for the response. Formatting like that did not work and no I have never used a local_file before. When you say share my code, what would you like to see? Everything is functional without this part, one just has to connect to the db manually. The file path be from my IDE right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the specified file path should look like this: `"${path.module}/db.sql"`